# How to split string in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to create dataframe from list  and I tried this code

```py
table[1] = ['SKU1222',
 'Test Import Name - Description Goes Here\nLabor - Example labor item. Quantity is number of hours spent, \nprice is hourly rate. Quantity accepts decimal values.',
 '1\n1.5',
 '$10.00\n$100.00',
 '$10.00\n$150.00']



import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(table[1])
df = df.transpose()
df

0   1   2   3   4
0   SKU1222 Test Import Name - Description Goes Here\nLabo...   1\n1.5  $10.00\n$100.00 $10.00\n$150.00
```

I need table look like this...

```py
0   1       2                                        3   4        5
0   SKU1222 Test Import Name - Description Goes Here 1   $10.00   $10.00
1           Labor - Example labor item               1.5 $100.00  $150.00
```

Comment: do you want to split into words?

Comment: I want to split it to create dataframe

Comment: can you depict the desired result in say a table form?

Comment: You have to somehow show (_manually type in_) your desired output, how the resultant table (df) **should** look

Comment: Sorry I just edited the question from your suggestion

Comment: What happens to the remainder of the string? The second column has only part of it

Comment: I don't see an straightforward out-of-the-box method to achieve what you want, since arbitrarily you want to add a new row on the second column from the first break line, the problem I see is how do you know when the next item has a missing field

Comment: Where does the source for `table[1]` comes from?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez  the origin is an invoice, and the `table` is a list of lists

Comment: Can you share a bit more content from the table?

Comment: `table = [['CCooddee DDeessccrriippttiioonn QTY Price Line Total',
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None],
 ['SKU1222',
  'Test Import Name - Description Goes Here\nLabor - Example labor item. Quantity is number of hours spent, \nprice is hourly rate. Quantity accepts decimal values.',
  '1\n1.5',
  '$10.00\n$100.00',
  '$10.00\n$150.00'],
 ['Notes', None, None, None, None],
 ['An invoice note can go here. Multi-line and even multi-page notes are supported.',
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None],
 ['PPaayymmeenntt  DDeettaaiillss', None, None, None, None],
 ['', None, None, None, None]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is in really bad shape. For now, I can suggest you the following, though this is not very useful as it would seem to me:

```py
import pandas as pd

table = [['CCooddee DDeessccrriippttiioonn QTY Price Line Total',   None,   None,   None,   None],  \
['SKU1222',   'Test Import Name - Description Goes Here\nLabor - Example labor item. Quantity is number of hours spent, \nprice is hourly rate. Quantity accepts decimal values.',   '1\n1.5',   '$10.00\n$100.00',   '$10.00\n$150.00'], \
 ['Notes', None, None, None, None],  ['An invoice note can go here. Multi-line and even multi-page notes are supported.',   None,   None,   None,   None],\
  ['PPaayymmeenntt  DDeettaaiillss', None, None, None, None],  ['', None, None, None, None]]


data = [x.split('\n') for x in table[1]]
maxlen = max([len(x) for x in data])
cols = ['ID', 'Desc', 'Qty', 'Price', 'Total']
data = {k:v if len(v)==maxlen else v+['']*(maxlen-len(v)) for k,v in zip(cols, data)}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)
```

The dataframe generated is as follows:

```bash
        ID                                               Desc  Qty    Price     Total
0  SKU1222           Test Import Name - Description Goes Here    1   $10.00    $10.00 
1           Labor - Example labor item. Quantity is number...  1.5  $100.00   $150.00 
2           price is hourly rate. Quantity accepts decimal...
```